# Game Center Multiplayer using GKMatch but seems can't be connected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center

Hi I'm a new bie in Game Center for iOS.  I'm trying to add the multiplayer feature using matches to my game and following the documentation.

So far I reached a point where 2 of my clients can successfully get a match, i.e. the matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch callback is called and a GKMatch object is delivered.

However after that I seems to be stuck there forever, because according to the documentation,  I'll have to wait until all the players (2 in my case) are actually connected before starting my game.   But it seems the match:player:didChangeState callback is never called to indicate a successful connection.   Well, I'm sure my clients are all in the same wifi network ( or is it a must?)  Could any one enlighten me on this case?  Do I have to do any extra things to make the clients to connect?    Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Some updates to the problem, I finally did a wireshark capture of all the traffics,  and I just found out that Game Center needs to use STUN to overcome Routers/NAT/Firewalls, and by taking a peek at the RFC, it says "STUN does not work when it is used to obtain an address to communicate with a peer which happens to be behind the same NAT. ",  OK, I guess this might be the root of my problem , 2 of my clients are both in the private network (192.168.2.x) of a wifi router.  But I'm not sure what's the best way to overcome this when I do the testing....any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem as you have, but I don't think this STUN issue you mention above is the problem as I do my testing with devices connected to two different NAT networks.

Answer (score 3):

So I was running into this and the solution (for me) was somewhat embarrasing.  I had copied and pasted a bunch of the code from the Apple docs..and they left out an obvious step.  They never actually set the match's delegate!

My code now is:

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
self.myMatch = match; // Use a retaining property to retain the match.
self.myMatch.delegate = self;  // THIS LINE WAS MISSING IN THE APPLE DOCS.  DOH.
// Start the game using the match.
NSLog(@"Match started! Expected Player Count:%d  %@",match.expectedPlayerCount, match.playerIDs);}
```

Once I actually set the match delegate, the functions get called.  Doh.

Answer (score 2):

When you get the GKMatch object, be sure to check the expectedPlayerCount property.  It is possible that the other player is already connected, and thus you will not get a match:player:didChangeState on the delegate.

Comment: The same code works in the same NAT but not in different ones. So thats not the case.

Comment: Did you check the property?  This is entirely timing related, and thus will behave differently on different networks.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with a friend. The solution was quite strange but it works afterwards. On all devices you have to enable the Notifications (Sounds/Alerts/Badges) for the Game Center inside the Settings/Notifications options. Afterwards we could establish a connection and did receive a match object

Comment: I don't know if that works as I am doing my development testing with ios simulators. One running on my native machine and the second one running in vmware on os x server. Notifications are not included in the ios simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your callback matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch

Add this code then you'll see the callback "match:player:didChangeState" being called by GC

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;
    [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] addPlayersToMatch:match matchRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSError* error) {
        if(error)
            NSLog(@"Error adding player: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

It was working all along. The only difference is that... when you use invites the event "didChangeState" doensn't get called. You're connected without notice and you can start to receive data. I never tried to send/receive data... cuz i was expecting the event first, but i did send something by mistake one time, and it worked. :)

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *) match {    
    //Dismiss window
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    //Retain match
    self.myMatch = match; 

    //Delegate
    myMatch.delegate = self;


    //Flag
    matchStarted = TRUE;

   //Other stuff
}

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state  {
    //This code gets called only on auto-match
}
```

The above code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've set your class as the delegate for `GKSession`. The class will need to implement the `GKSessionDelegate` protocol... otherwise, it'll never receive this callback. Here's the [protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSessionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks sam, but I'm actually implementing Multiplay using match instead of peer-to-peer. So I have implemented and set correctly the GKMatchDelegate protocol and GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, but  seems couldn't receive the match:player:didChangeState callback.