# My GKMatch has no players...?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit, game-center

- I successfully made a matchmaking screen appear.
- I run my game in my iPhone and also in the simulator.
- In both cases I log in with a different Game Center account.
- I go to the matchmaking screen in both games. I press "play now". Both games begin looking for a match.
- Finally, both games find a match and call the function below:

---

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)match
{
    self.myMatch = match;
    NSLog(@"%d",[[self.myMatch playerIDs]count]);

}
```

---

But my console returns 0. Shouldn't it return 2 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you are not actually connecting them?

Are you in fact using `GKMatchmaker` and `GKMatchmakerViewController`?

In your testing, you are sure you are using TWO DIFFERENT game center accounts?

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the game center system.

Comment: I will soon check with two iPhones with two different accounts, and will get back to you. And thanks for the bounty :)

Answer (score 4):

GKMatchmaker returns you a match *before* connections have been established between players; at this stage, all the players are in the process of connecting to each other.

> The playerIDs property is initially set to the number of players already connected to the match; the array may be empty. Whenever a player is connected to the match, that player’s player identifier is added to the array.

Additionally, some players can fail to connect (I haven't tested this case so I don't know if you get an error returned)

What you're looking for is `GKMatch.expectedPlayerCount`

> The value of this property is decremented whenever a player connects to the match. When its value reaches zero, all expected players are connected, and your game can begin the match.

I also suspect that `GKMatch.playerIDs` does not include the player; i.e. you'll probably see expectedPlayerCount = 1 immediately after connecting.

I'm not sure what GameKit does about threads.

Comment: I will check this out immediately :)

Comment: Very interesting, it seems *[self.myMatch expectedPlayerCount]* stays on 1. Therefore I guess I really didn't manage to connect both players, right? But that's weird, the iPhone and the simulator both "found a match" and closed the matchmaking view, so I expected they were already connected..... and sure I'm using two different Game Center accounts. I haven't had the chance to test on two iPhones though, but got any idea about this?

Comment: I'd try with a "real" device (I've never actually tried on the simulator). It also is sounding like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337481/game-center-multiplayer-using-gkmatch-but-seems-cant-be-connected

Comment: Did you find a solution to this between simulator and device? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @HoratiuParaschiv: Yeah: don't use the simulator for Game Center. Use a real device.