# Game center didChangeState and didReceiveData fromRemotePlayer remote player is not calling in ios 8 & ios 9

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, game-center, game-development

i am making `realtime multiplayer game` in `cocos 2d-x` for `iOS`. According to my flow i am doing following things with the help of this link  [iOS Game Center GameKit Programmatic Invite Matchmaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623311/ios-game-center-gamekit-programmatic-invite-matchmaking][1]):

**Step 1:** Authenticate your player

**Step 2:** right after authentication set inviteHandler.

**Step 3:** Get your list of friend playerIds (not alias)

**Step 4:** Fourth, Setup your GKMatchRequest something like this... I am inviting all the friends.

**Step 5:** Fifth, Use the request to call `findMatchForRequest:withCompletionHandler`.

**Step 6:** Sixth, this sends the request to the other player and if they accept the "inviteHandler" from the second step gets called.

**Step 7:** Seventh, the "inviteHandler" from the second step gets the match for the GKInvite!

**Step 8:** Eighth, the "inviteeResponseHandler" from the fourth step gets called which finished the match!

Till here my code is working fine after it. 3 steps after these steps are not working can please anyone help me out ?

**Step 9:** Ninth, create a `didChangeState` from `GKMatchDelegate` to handle the finalization of the match.

**Step 10:** Send message

**Step 11:** Eleventh, create a `didReceiveData` from `GKMatchDelegate`.

```
[_match sendData:data toPlayers:_currentFriends dataMode:GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error:&error];

[_match sendData:data toPlayers:_currentFriends withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable error:&error];

[_match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error:&error];
```

And its delegate method is:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID {
NSLog(@"Received Data");
[_delegate match:match didReceiveData:data fromPlayer:playerID];
}
```

I have also tried:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromRemotePlayer:(GKPlayer *)player
{
    NSLog(@"received DAta");
}
```

Comment: When you use invites the event "didChangeState" doesn't get called. Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337481/game-center-multiplayer-using-gkmatch-but-seems-cant-be-connected

Comment: @Vizllx but my data is also not receiving on other side how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:this tutorial shows a simple application with game center

http://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1